# finding and drawing bounding boxes

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, bounding-box

I currently have a 2D array of values. I am currently trying to find areas of it with values that are significantly different and draw bounding boxes around them.

Currently, I have used to scikit-image to threshold my values, by doing

```
from skimage import filters
val = filters.threshold_otsu(zo)
mask = zo < val
```

This mask gives me an array of Trues and Falses, like:

```
[[F, T, T, F],
 [F, T, F, F],
 [F, F, F, F],
 [F, F, F, T]
]
```

Now, using this, I would like to draw a rectangle around each of the two groups of the `Trues`. However, I am finding it difficult to perform this. OpenCV seems to be able to perform actions like this simply (see: [Drawing bounding rectangles around multiple objects in binary image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923800/drawing-bounding-rectangles-around-multiple-objects-in-binary-image-in-python)) using the function cv2.boundingRect(). However, since my original object is not an image I am not using it.

Is there a simple function in Python to calculate the areas of bounding boxes (kinda like cv2.boundingRect()), or a way to pass a 2d matrix like the one above to OpenCV to be able to use it directly?

Comment: T and F are likely represented as 1 and 0. So your array should be simply a bumpy array for which OpenCv can operate. You would then need to get contours and from the contours get the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example drawing bounding boxes about regions in the scikit-image gallery here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html

You need two things:

(1) [label](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) your regions so that they are two distinct regions. ie your image above would become:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 2]]
```

(2) Use [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) and `props.bbox` to find the bounding box of each region, which you can then use to draw in matplotlib or your software of choice.

So, in the [example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html), search for "label" and "bbox" to see usage examples.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - thank you!